# systemd-networkd: concerning the difference between `/etc/systemd/network` and `/usr/lib/systemd/network`

Tags: networking, systemd, containers

I started experimenting systemd-networkd on both host machine and systemd-nspawn containers. After having disabled all other network management services like NetworkManager, on **host** machine I created .network files under

```
/etc/systemd/network
```

and everything worked fine. In systemd-nspawn containers instead, the system ignored the .network file I inserted in

```
/etc/systemd/network/
```

even if I correctly matched network adapter name (host0) in `[Match]` .network file section. Later by using

```
# networkctl status host0
```

I have found out that such interface was taking the configuration from

```
/usr/lib/systemd/network/80-container-host0.network
```

file. I inserted in it the correct networking settings and everything worked fine.

From `man systemd-networkd`:

```
The configuration files are read from the files located in the system network directory /usr/lib/systemd/network, the volatile runtime network directory  /run/systemd/network and the local administration network directory /etc/systemd/network.
```

Questions:

1. What is the difference between `system network directory` and `local administration network directory`?
2. Why the container gets automatically networks settings from `/usr/lib/systemd/network/` directory?

Answer (score 2):

The "system network directory" is where packages should install files.

The "local administration directory" is where human administrators are expected to add and edit custom files.

You report putting a file in the "/etc/systemd" directory, but having a parallel file in "/usr/lib/systemd" seemingly override it.

The files in "/etc/systemd" are supposed to take precedence in the event of a conflict.  Did you notice this other part of the `systemd-networkd` man page?

> Network configurations applied before networkd is started are not removed, and static configuration applied by networkd is not removed
>   when networkd exits. Dynamic configuration applied
>     by networkd may also optionally be left in place on shutdown. This ensures restarting networkd does not cut the network connection,
>   and, in particular, that it is safe to transition
>        between the initrd and the real root, and back.

The way I read this, you might need to full stop the network management to make a new configuration file take affect.

Try:

```
sudo systemctl stop systemd-networkd
sudo systemctl start systemd-networkd
```

Then see if the new files you created in `/etc/systemd` have started to be active.